# Being asked for domain password by IT admin

Tags: security, android, intune

I'm a user, in an org of around 950 people, with a new Android smart phone being set up by our IT team. To set up apps (e.g. Outlook, Teams) on the phone, the service desk analyst has asked me to send my Windows password to him by email. There's nothing malicious in this, and I can easily change it afterwards, but this seems like the wrong approach in a big-ish enterprise with a 'proper' IT setup in every other respect.

What would be a more resilient, more secure alternative? Aren't there admin-level tools that can support the config piece without credentials being shared?

Comment: You should report this to your infosec team ASAP, other users may have already provided their passwords. Nobody should ever ask you for your domain password.

Comment: it could be a **Social engineering pen testing** If he is the real admin IT ask him to change the win password and give it to you after that he will know the password in a safe way that does not include you giving it to him

Comment: Thank you -- I'm reasonably confident the request is from a legitimate service desk tech. Agree it's the wrong approach. Good idea on asking the tech to reset my domain password.

Answer (score 2):

> To set up apps (e.g. Outlook, Teams) on the phone, the service desk analyst has asked me to send my Windows password to him by email

I don't think there is a way to set up apps on Android on behalf of somebody else, so asking for your password is really the only way.

Is it a good practice?
Absolutely not.

What would be better?
In theory the IT guy should at most install the apps for you and you should be the one signing in to them with your account. If you get stuck, than they could help you (maybe with a screen sharing session if you can't meet in person)

Comment: Thanks -- So Microsoft Intune doesn't cover the configuration of and authentication into individual device apps?